How to change the border color only for the header line of a longtable?
I have a tcolorbox containing a longtable. To make the header line better visible I wish to change the border color of the header row (only this row in the table). Is this possible?
Here is a complete testcase:
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[total={15.24cm,22.86cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{microtype}
%
% For creating new commands with an arbitrary number of arguments
\usepackage{newfile}
%
%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[listings,skins,most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
%
%
%
%
% Define a header style command
\newcommand{\longTabHeaderstyle}[1]{\textcolor{white}{#1}}
%
%
%
%
% Space before the table
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
%
% Space after the table
\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
%
% Space from the left before the table
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
%
% Space from the right after the table
\setlength{\LTright}{0pt}
%
%
% Define the printDbBreakableTable environment
\newenvironment{printDbBreakableTable}[4]{%
  \getLTwidth
  % Start the tcolorbox
  \begin{tcolorbox}[%
    % Make the box content breakable across pages
    breakable,%
    text width={\LTwidth},
    %
    % Set background color of the box
    colback=white,%
    %
    % Set frame color of the box
    colframe=black,%
    %
    % Set space below the title
    bottomtitle=1mm,%
    %
    % Set space above the title
    toptitle=1mm,%
    %
    % Set thickness of left border
    leftrule=0.15mm,%
    %
    % Set thickness of right border
    rightrule=0.15mm,%
    %
    % Set thickness of bottom border
    bottomrule=0.15mm,%
    %
    % Center the title
    title=\centering #1,%
    %
    % Remove internal padding
    boxsep=0pt,%
    %
    % Remove top padding
    top=0pt,%
    %
    % Remove bottom padding
    bottom=0pt,%
    %
    % Remove left padding
    left=0pt,%
    %
    % Remove right padding
    right=0pt%
  ]%
  \par
  %
  % Begin table structure by indicating the number of columns
  \begin{longtable}%
    {#2}%
    %
    % Set header row color
    \rowcolor{black}%
    %
    % The content of the header row
    #3%
    \endhead
    \hline
    %
    % Insert the table's main content
    #4%
  \end{longtable}%
  % End the tcolorbox
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\LTwidth}
\newcommand{\getLTwidth}[1][\empty]% #1 = longtable index (optional)
{\bgroup% for \count1 and \LT@entry
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \count1=\value{LT@tables}% default
    \advance\count1 by 1
  \else
    \count1=#1\relax
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{LT@\@roman\count1}{\LTwidth=\textwidth}{%
    \LTwidth=0pt%
    \def\LT@entry##1##2{\advance\LTwidth by ##2}%
    \csname LT@\@roman\count1\endcsname
  }%
  \global\LTwidth=\LTwidth
\egroup}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\addtolength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{printDbBreakableTable}
  {Test a long table}
  {c|c|c|c}
  {%
    \longTabHeaderstyle{H1} & \longTabHeaderstyle{H2} &
    \longTabHeaderstyle{H3} & \longTabHeaderstyle{H4} \\\hline }
  {%
CellValue-1-1 & CellValue-2-1 & CellValue-3-1 & CellValue-4-1 \\\hline
CellValue-1-2 & CellValue-2-2 & CellValue-3-2 & CellValue-4-2 \\\hline
CellValue-1-3 & CellValue-2-3 & CellValue-3-3 & CellValue-4-3 \\\hline
CellValue-1-4 & CellValue-2-4 & CellValue-3-4 & CellValue-4-4 \\\hline
CellValue-1-5 & CellValue-2-5 & CellValue-3-5 & CellValue-4-5 \\
  }
  
\end{printDbBreakableTable}

\end{document}

Thanks in advance

Have a look at the tabularray package. It makes it easy to customise such things.

You mean to use tabularray instead of longtable? Because multipage breakable is a requirement for me.

Do have a look at tabularray. It has environments which allow page breaks.

I will. I see that at chapter 4, indeed they talk about long tables : https://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf. If that is the case, and it can go inside a tcolorbox, then I may as well leave longtable and go for longtable. I'm going to read that chapter and see if I can adapt the program with this new package.

Ok, I tried a first version. Indeed the use of [rowhead=1, row{1} = {yellow}] after \begin{longtblr}, permits to set easily the background color for the header row. However as I said, I need the table to be inside a tcolorbox and here I noticed two big limitations: (1) I have to use only X|X|X instead of c|c|c or p{...}|p{...}|p{...} otherwise the table will be either shorter or longer than the tcolorbox. (2) if lontblr is used alone, page breaks are managed properly and at the beginning of each page, the header is repeated as expected. None of these happen if the table is inside tcolorbox.
